# How to Update sql table using while loop

Tags: sql

Am updating my sql table using while loops , In my table records "id" are in this order 27,28,29,30 upto 45. am trying to update thise "id" into 2,3,4,5 upto 16 i used this loop but am getting error only

```
DECLARE @a INT 
DECLARE @b INT
SET @a = 2
SET @b = 27
WHILE @b < 42
BEGIN
exec sp_executesql 'UPDATE Cpart2_TEST_2 SET id = @a where id = @b   

SET @a = @a + 1
SET @b = @b + 1
END
```

This is the error message

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'DECLARE @a INT

```
DECLARE @b INT
SET @a = 2
SET @b = 27
WHILE @b < 42
BEGIN
' at line 1
```

Comment: *error only* is not a valid error message. Please post the exact text of the error and include which SQL Server version you are using.

Comment: **WHAT** database system are you using? The `sp_executesql` seems to indicate SQL Server, while the error message makes a reference to MySQL - so which is it now really??

Comment: The real question is actually: *why* are you trying to "renumber" the IDs. The value of a primary key (and the column name `ID` seems to indicate one) has no meaning and it's totally irrelevant if the ID is 1, 27 or 1563265378.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your exec line to:

```
exec sp_executesql 'UPDATE Cpart2_TEST_2 SET id = ' + CAST(@a AS nvarchar(3)) + ' where id = + ' CAST(@b AS nvarchar(3))
```

I haven't parsed this so it may have syntax errors. But get that working, and you should be good.

One thing to consider... if 'id' is an IDENTITY column, you will probably not be able to alter it.